# Canned green and yellow beans

Tags: beans

I have cooked the beans drained and boiled water filled hot jars boiled water bath for the right time .They sealed and days later popped seal I then feed my hens but that was for us not them

Comment: What is your question? Animal feed is probably off topic here...

Comment: @Robert Regardless, a popped seal on a boiled-jar means the seal wasn't good, and means it could be unsafe to eat, even for animals.

Comment: Beans are definitely low acid.  Water bath is not sufficient by modern standards.  Yes, my mom and grand mothers did it too and survived.  But modern standards say the risk is too high.

Comment: There is no "right time" for boiling water bath canning of low-acid foods. If you go to any reputable canning information source, you will not find a time for this method and that type of food - because there is no safe length of time. You need the additional temperature provided by pressure canning, or you need to pickle the beans to make them acid first. Additionally, you may well poison your chickens feeding them these spoiled beans.

Comment: @Robert that doesn't sound like bad sealing, that sounds like the beans fermenting, producing gas and negating the seal!

Answer (score 5):

The accepted canon on canning beans via non-pickling, non-pressure methods is that it is not safe and comes with the risk of spoilage - as you experienced. Also, do not assume non-popping, not obviously spoiled jars of beans canned that way are safe. Also, do not feed microbially spoiled food like that to animals, it can make them sick too.